# is there a reason my .jumbotron p isn't formatting the correct size?

Tags: css

i'm relatively new with this stuff, but i can't seem to figure out why the size isn't formatting?

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/YxLLQw

```
.jumbotron p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It's because of how codepen renders your code. If you take a look at the source code, your codepen css is  placed before your bootstrap css so the bootstrap css takes precedence. Just add `!important` next to the attribute for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have written the `link` tag inside the **HTML** section of the codepen.

To add any external css make use of **GearIcon** on the CSS Section and add the links there. Doing so, make the libraries get added on top of the webpage and your css written in the **CSS** section can override those styles.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Josan already commented: There is a rule for ".jumbotron p" in bootstrap CSS defining "font-size". To make your CSS override that, link your external style sheet after bootstrap.